# how to make stored procedure of this query in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
SELECT    IQ, PARENT_EQ_NAME1, REASON_NAME FROM (
SELECT     SUM(IQ) AS IQ, PARENT_EQ_NAME1, REASON_NAME1 AS REASON_NAME FROM 
(
SELECT     REASON_NAME, IQ, PARENT_EQ_NAME1, rank1, 
                                                                      CASE WHEN rank1 > 5 THEN 'SUM OF REMAINING' ELSE REASON_NAME END REASON_NAME1
FROM (

SELECT     REASON_NAME, IQ, PARENT_EQ_NAME1, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY PARENT_EQ_NAME1
                                                                       ORDER BY IQ DESC) AS rank1
FROM (
SELECT SUM(TH.IMPACT_QTY ) IQ,TH.PARENT_EQ_NAME1,TH.REASON_NAME FROM 
(
select impact_qty,eq_name PARENT_EQ_NAME1,reason_name from c_maaden_vw_losses_by_area where PARENT_Eq_name=:parenteqName
AND (dvtn_start_dt_tm >= :StartDate) 
                                                   AND (dvtn_end_dt_tm <= :EndDate) AND (TRGT_TYPE IN (:Type))

-- eq_name
UNION ALL 
select impact_qty,parent_eq_name PARENT_EQ_NAME1, reason_name  from c_maaden_vw_losses_by_area where
parent_Eq_name in (select distinct eq_name from ip_equip_hierarchy where parent_eq_name =:parenteqName  ) 
AND (dvtn_start_dt_tm >= :StartDate) 
 AND (dvtn_end_dt_tm <= :EndDate) AND (TRGT_TYPE IN (:Type)) -- parent_Eq_name
UNION ALL 
SELECT     CA.IMPACT_QTY, 
Case  
  when IH.parent_eq_name is null then CA.parent_eq_name  
 else IH.parent_eq_name end parent_EQ_NAME1,reason_name
                                      FROM          C_MAADEN_VW_LOSSES_BY_AREA CA  left outer join

 (select distinct t1.parent_eq_name GP_eq_name ,t2.parent_eq_name , T2.Eq_name from ip_equip_hierarchy T1, ip_equip_hierarchy T2
where T1.eq_name=t2.Parent_EQ_name and t1.parent_eq_name= :parenteqName   and T1.hierarchy_typ='ASSET') IH
                                      on CA.parent_eq_name=IH.eq_name
                                      where CA.parent_Eq_name
                                      in (select distinct eq_name from ip_equip_hierarchy where parent_eq_name in (select distinct eq_name
                                      from ip_equip_hierarchy
                                      where parent_Eq_name = :parenteqName  )  ) AND (dvtn_start_dt_tm >= :StartDate) 
 AND (dvtn_end_dt_tm <= :EndDate) AND (TRGT_TYPE IN (:Type))  

)   TH

where  NOT(TH.REASON_NAME='Other' AND TH.PARENT_EQ_NAME1 = :parenteqName )
AND    (TH.REASON_NAME NOT IN ('DIGESTION SLURRY FEED PUMP', 'CAB TEST OR ACID CLEANING'))
GROUP BY TH.PARENT_EQ_NAME1,TH.REASON_NAME

)))
GROUP BY PARENT_EQ_NAME1, REASON_NAME1

union all 
SELECT    SUM(IMPACT_QTY) AS IQ,:parenteqName as PARENT_EQ_NAME1, REASON_NAME from C_MAADEN_VW_LOSSES_BY_AREA
where eq_name=:parenteqName and REASON_NAME= 'Other' AND (dvtn_start_dt_tm >= :StartDate) 
                                                   AND (dvtn_end_dt_tm <= :EndDate) AND (TRGT_TYPE IN (:Type)) 
                                                   group by PARENT_EQ_NAME,REASON_NAME  ) order by IQ DESC
```

Comment: What exactly is your requirement?

Comment: this is my query and i want to make it as stored procedure in oracle .

Comment: Have a look at the [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_procedure.htm#LNPLS01373). It will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are expecting to write simple procedure with above query. so i have created the procedure with your SQL query as below.
procedure will create. But there is no use of this procedure.

```
Create procedure p(parenteqName  Varchar2(30),
                               StartDate          Date,
                               EndDate            Date,
                               Type                   Varchar2(10))

V_IQ                              Number(10);
V_ PARENT_EQ_NAME1 varchar2(30);
V_ REASON_NAME        varchar2(30);

Begin

SELECT    IQ, PARENT_EQ_NAME1, REASON_NAME  into V_IQ , V_ PARENT_EQ_NAME1, V_ REASON_NAME FROM (
SELECT     SUM(IQ) AS IQ, PARENT_EQ_NAME1, REASON_NAME1 AS REASON_NAME FROM 
(
SELECT     REASON_NAME, IQ, PARENT_EQ_NAME1, rank1, 
                                                                      CASE WHEN rank1 > 5 THEN 'SUM OF REMAINING' ELSE REASON_NAME END REASON_NAME1
FROM (

SELECT     REASON_NAME, IQ, PARENT_EQ_NAME1, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY PARENT_EQ_NAME1
                                                                       ORDER BY IQ DESC) AS rank1
FROM (
SELECT SUM(TH.IMPACT_QTY ) IQ,TH.PARENT_EQ_NAME1,TH.REASON_NAME FROM 
(
select impact_qty,eq_name PARENT_EQ_NAME1,reason_name from c_maaden_vw_losses_by_area where PARENT_Eq_name= parenteqName
AND (dvtn_start_dt_tm >=  StartDate) 
AND (dvtn_end_dt_tm <=  EndDate) AND (TRGT_TYPE IN (Type))

-- eq_name
UNION ALL 
select impact_qty,parent_eq_name PARENT_EQ_NAME1, reason_name  from c_maaden_vw_losses_by_area where
parent_Eq_name in (select distinct eq_name from ip_equip_hierarchy where parent_eq_name =parenteqName  ) 
AND (dvtn_start_dt_tm >= StartDate) 
 AND (dvtn_end_dt_tm <= EndDate) AND (TRGT_TYPE IN (Type)) -- parent_Eq_name
UNION ALL 
SELECT     CA.IMPACT_QTY, 
Case  
  when IH.parent_eq_name is null then CA.parent_eq_name  
 else IH.parent_eq_name end parent_EQ_NAME1,reason_name
                                      FROM          C_MAADEN_VW_LOSSES_BY_AREA CA  left outer join

 (select distinct t1.parent_eq_name GP_eq_name ,t2.parent_eq_name , T2.Eq_name from ip_equip_hierarchy T1, ip_equip_hierarchy T2
where T1.eq_name=t2.Parent_EQ_name and t1.parent_eq_name= parenteqName   and T1.hierarchy_typ='ASSET') IH
                                      on CA.parent_eq_name=IH.eq_name
                                      where CA.parent_Eq_name
                                      in (select distinct eq_name from ip_equip_hierarchy where parent_eq_name in (select distinct eq_name
                                      from ip_equip_hierarchy
                                      where parent_Eq_name = parenteqName  )  ) AND (dvtn_start_dt_tm >= StartDate) 
 AND (dvtn_end_dt_tm <= EndDate) AND (TRGT_TYPE IN (Type))  

)   TH

where  NOT(TH.REASON_NAME='Other' AND TH.PARENT_EQ_NAME1 = parenteqName )
AND    (TH.REASON_NAME NOT IN ('DIGESTION SLURRY FEED PUMP', 'CAB TEST OR ACID CLEANING'))
GROUP BY TH.PARENT_EQ_NAME1,TH.REASON_NAME

)))
GROUP BY PARENT_EQ_NAME1, REASON_NAME1

union all 
SELECT    SUM(IMPACT_QTY) AS IQ,parenteqName as PARENT_EQ_NAME1, REASON_NAME from C_MAADEN_VW_LOSSES_BY_AREA
where eq_name=parenteqName and REASON_NAME= 'Other' AND (dvtn_start_dt_tm >= StartDate) 
                                                   AND (dvtn_end_dt_tm <= EndDate) AND (TRGT_TYPE IN (Type)) 
                                                   group by PARENT_EQ_NAME,REASON_NAME  ) order by IQ DESC

Exception
When others then
Null;
End;
```

Better you google it before asking questions here.

Comment: Please describe your changes to the query and maybe give some explanation & documentation too.